# Why is there an Error?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

The error is saying that nil is not an option, but then what else would I put?

```
import UIKit
import Metal
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var device: MTLDevice! = nil
    device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    var metalLayer: CAMetalLayer! = nil
    metalLayer = CAMetalLayer()
    metalLayer.device = device
    metalLayer.pixelFormat = .BGRA8Unorm
    metalLayer.framebufferOnly = true
    metalLayer.frame = view.layer.frame
    view.layer.addSublayer(metalLayer)

    let vertexData:[Float] = [
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0,0.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0
    ]

    var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer! = nil
    let dataSize = vertexData.count * sizeofValue(vertexData[0])
    vertexBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(vertexData, length: dataSize, options: nil)
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to be given a line number.

Answer (score 4):

You should put `[]` if you have no `options:` to supply.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable with a non optional type, you don't have to initialize it. If you want this variable to be optional, however, you'll need to declare it as `let metalLayer: CAMetalLayer?` and then you can set that equal to nil.